# call a Grpc Service inside Node.js

Tags: node.js, grpc, proto, grpc-node

I am using node.js to design a GraphQL server and for resolver section i am using a GRPC(proto) service,so i have another GRPC service designed in node. Now i am unable to understand how to call the service function inside GraphQL server.

AS in C# first we have to create a .cs file from proto then give the reference of generate .cs files to another service and create request and call the function of GRPC service using APIGateway.

I searched on google,some blogs are suggesting to generate .js file and give the reference of generated .js file inside GraphQL server and call the function of gRPC service.
Is there any another way to call the GRPC Service inside node.js?